# Menu link not visible odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm install my custom module but module link in menu is not visible!

I'm trying to change sequences but again in not visible, in apps/modul name stay:

Created Menus 
MY MENU

Where is problem here?

```
<menuitem name="MY MENU" id="my_menu_1" action="action_my_menu_form" sequence="55"/>
```

Comment: 1. Try giving access rights to that model for that user, which is been used for that menu.  2./ Try giving parent menu, under which this menu should appear.

Comment: @HardikPatadia Hi, I'm add parent menu eg. Sale but not visible again, after try create group in settings also can't find my menu name in menus tab.

Comment: Set default access rights for your model. that should help. Otherwise only the admin is allowed to see the menu item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Odoo Menu-Item parent-id is required.

If you not give parent menu item then odoo will consider menu item as Parent Menu item.

You have done same thing.create menu item without parent-id,so odoo will consider as parent menu.

Ex:

Sales Is parent Menu. ( In base module)

```
    <menuitem name="Sales"
        id="menu_base_partner"
        groups="base.group_sale_salesman"
        sequence="20"/>
```

Product is Child Menu.

```
    <menuitem id="menu_product" name="Products" parent="base.menu_base_partner" action="product_action_window" sequence="9"/>
```

Parent Menu item is **base.menu_base_partner**.

Child Menu item is **menu_product**.

If you create only Parent menu item then Child menu item will not visible in the system.

Comment: Hello, My module work fine on local (menu is visible) but after install on online server menu is hidden! I don't know how fix problem, also on new online database work fine. Maybe is problem in another module. Crazy situation...

Comment: A menu in Odoo doesn't require a parent. When the menu doesn't have a parent it simply becomes an item in the top menu bar. Which probably is what the author is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When the menu is not shown (if any one know other cases put it in comment ) sorry for my english:

1. The menu has no child menu and it has not an action
2. the menu has childrens menus but also the children have no action
3. menu or childs menus have action but you are not allowed by group security.
4. (ir.model.access)you have acces to menu but you don't have acces to read record from the model related to the action. super user (administrator) can acces any record.

   5. or you didn't upgrade you module correctly the menu is not loaded at all for this problem see in developper mode if the menu is loaded to the database.